# what is the linux-kernel-devel equivalent in 12.04.2 LTS 3.5.0?

Tags: installation, kernel, package-management

apologies for the noob question, but when I try to

```
sudo apt-get install Linux-kernel-devel
```

I get the following:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-kernel-devel  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package linux-kernel-devel
```

I have tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)  
sudo apt-get install build-essentials  
sudo apt-get install Linux-headers-generic
```

with no joy... any suggestions?

Comment: What do you expect the package linux-kernel-devel to do? Are you looking for the headers, or something else?

Answer (score 20):

#### Executive Summary

You probably want to install the package called `linux-headers-generic`.

If running `uname -r` gives you something other than `generic` after the version number, substitute that for `generic` in `linux-headers-generic`. (This might be `server` or `generic-pae` on some installations of some Ubuntu releases, and there are a few other occasional kernel "flavors.")

Since you most likely needs this so that you can build a driver (which might be automated, you might not be "building it yourself"), it's a good idea to install `build-essential` too to make it so you'll probably have all the necessary tools.

#### Full Explanation

To the best of my knowledge, no operating system has a package called `Linux-kernel-devel`. This is for two reasons:

- Package names starting with capital letters are extremely rare, for any Unix-like OS.
- GNU/Linux operating systems typically name their kernel-related packages so that the names contain the word *kernel* or the word *linux*, but not both. (On Ubuntu, it's the word *linux*.)

It's common for kernel-related packages on systems that use the Red Hat Package Manager (`rpm`) and related utilities to have `kernel` in the name of their packages. For example, Mageia has [a number of packages](http://mageia.madb.org/package/list/t_search/kernel-devel/application/0) whose names start with `kernel` and end in `devel`. These packages almost always (on Mageia and any OS that has them) provide the *header files* needed to build drivers from source for use with the kernel. They may also provide related utilities to facilitate. These packages:

- do *not* provide the full source code of the kernel. That's provided by other packages.
- do *not* provide a pre-compiled, usable kernel. That's provided by other packages.
- do *not* provide a compiler or most other purpose build tools. Those, too, are provided by other packages.

In Ubuntu, as can be seen [in the list here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta), the packages that provide kernel headers have names that start with `linux-headers`. Usually the correct package to install is `linux-headers-generic`. However, to be sure of what package to install to get headers that correspond to your currently running kernel, run:

```
uname -r
```

You'll get output that looks something like:

```
3.5.0-36-generic
```

That is, you'll have a version number (which will include `.` characters and usually at least one `-`), followed by a `-`, followed by one or more words indicating which kind of kernel you are running.

If you *just* want the headers for the specific version you happen to be running now, you could install the package whose name is `linux-headers-*` where `*` is replaced by the full output of `uname -r`. For example, on my system, I could run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-36-generic
```

I could even automate it:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

These approaches are equivalent, but they are not usually the best way to go.

Instead, you usually will want to install the [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) that always provides the newest kernel headers as an update (by perpetually depending on whatever header package is newest). This parallels the way your compiled, running kernel is installed and gets updated. To do that, look just at the part of `uname -r`'s output *after* the version number. That is, if `uname -r` gives you `3.5.0-36-generic`, take just the `generic` part.

Then install the package called `linux-headers-*` where `*` is replaced by that part. So, on my system, it would be `linux-headers-generic` and one way I could install it would be to run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

For most people it is `linux-headers-generic`, but depending on what Ubuntu release you're running, what architecture and type of device you're running it on, and how it is installed and configured, other possibilities include `generic-pae`, `highbank`, `omap`, `server`, and `virtual`.

#### Related Packages

[Header files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_file) facilitate developing and compiling/building software that uses facilities provided by the software whose header files are being used. The most common reason you might need kernel headers is if you are going to build a driver (a kernel module) from source code. Some applications, like VMware and VirtualBox, will sometimes require this, and will automate the build themselves.

In addition to header files, to build software a compiler and other tools are needed. To maximize the likelihood that you have the necessary tools, it's a good idea to install the `build-essential` package also.

It's uncommon for anyone to need the actual full kernel source code (unless, of course, you're planning on building your kernel from source). But if you do need that, you'll have to install another package too. In Ubuntu the package for full kernel source code is called `linux-source`. (This is in keeping with the Debian/Ubuntu convention of naming packages that provide substantive parts of the Linux kernel `linux` rather than `kernel`.)

#### If You Still Have Trouble

If you try to install any of these packages but experience problems, and you want help, then you will have to include the complete and exact text from the Terminal, including the lines where you typed commands. The best way to provide this is by editing your question, but if it is too long, you can paste it somewhere like http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide us with the URL where we can access it.

If you comment on this question, I'll be notified. You can edit your question and also comment here to call attention to the information you've provided in your question. (Important information is best kept in questions and answers.) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As the report said (E: Unable to locate package linux-kernel-devel) 
There are no packages like that. 
You can install every kernel version you want by downloading the debian kernel packages from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)

For example; we want to install kernel 3.9.8 (i386 architecture);
Download all *****i386.deb packages And also ******all.deb package to a folder.
Get in to the folder with cd command in terminal;

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo update-grub2
sudo reboot
```

This will install the kernel version you want. You can analyse the versions of the kernel mainline and longterm versions in this [site](https://www.kernel.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to map out yourself which specific deb's you need, but there is the debs you will need in [Ubunut's kernel builds](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

Honestly I'd first check with `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to make sure your running the latest kernel and won't need to do this again shortly.

Next look through the kernel build listing for your version that matches your `uname -r`. You need to look in each builds build.log to find out what head version they are mapping that build to. I have 3.5.0-34#55 listed as my kernel but this really maps out to build [3.5.7.14-quantal](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.7.14-quantal/). Install all the debs that correspond with that version to get your headers and such, and make sure you've got your build tools with `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Your mileage may very though depending on what you plan to do with the devel files.

Answer (score 0):

linux-kernel-devel is the name of a SUSE/Redhat package providing things like genksyms.

A very quick Google suggests that linux-headers-generic provides genksyms on Debian/Ubuntu.